# Changing default check_path behavior in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I need to return a JSON value after check_path checks user's credentials. Is there a configuration out there, somewhere.

I guess I could write a route for it and a controller, which calls the default check_path action and then returns the needed object. Problem with this approach is that I still don't know how to initialize default behavior.

Any help would be appreciated.